# should I write this code in my fragment/activity or in my viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I am new in Android MVVM, so I need to perform image cropping and asking permission to access image gallery, and I am confused whether these should be performed in my fragment or in my viewmodel.

to start cropping activity for pre-acquired image saved on the device I use this code

```
    CropImage.activity(selectedImagePosterFromGalleryUri)
        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
        .setRequestedSize(posterMaxWidthSize, posterMaxHeightSize, CropImageView.RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_INSIDE)
        .start(mContext, this)
```

the result (cropped image) from this code can be accessed in `onActivityResult` in my fragment when `requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE`

I am confused if it is considered as user input so I can put this code in my fragment or it is considered as logic / process so that should be placed in viewmodel ?

and also I need to ask permission to access gallery, to ask permisson I use a library and the code will be like this. do I have to put in fragment or viewmodel ?

```
    @AfterPermissionGranted(PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    private fun checkPermission() {


        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(mContext, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {


            chooseImageFromGallery()

        } else {

            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                this,
                "we need your permission to access your gallery",
                PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        }



    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this)
    }

    override fun onPermissionsDenied(requestCode: Int, perms: MutableList<String>) {

        if (EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(this, perms)) {

            // showing app setting, so the user eventually can switch the permission manually in the setting section
            AppSettingsDialog.Builder(this).build().show()
        }

    }

    override fun onPermissionsGranted(requestCode: Int, perms: MutableList<String>) {


    }
```

the one that make me confuse is this sentence from here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide ,it is said :

> It's a common mistake to write all your code in an Activity or a
>   Fragment. These UI-based classes should only contain logic that
>   handles UI and operating system interactions.

I am confused if cropping image and accessing gallery is considered as logic for handles UI and operating system interactions or not

I do not really understand to choose a code should be in viewmodel or in view (fragment/activity). for business logic, it is clear that is should be in viewmodel, but how about codes like these ? please help

Comment: Runtime permissions are definitely OS interactions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the google guy,

> ViewModels shouldn’t know anything about Android. This improves
>   testability, leak safety and modularity. A general rule of thumb is to
>   make sure there are no android.* imports in your ViewModels (with
>   exceptions like android.arch.*). The same applies to presenters.

If your cropping operation fulfills this condition then definately throw it in **ViewModel**.

For more details
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54

Comment: android.arch.* is the same as androidx.lifecycle.* right ? because I only have import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel and import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData

Comment: Yes they are used for same purposes. android.arch.lifecycle is legacy version of androidx.lifecycle. This is the actual part of ViewModel.

Answer (score -1):

You should place it in your ViewModel and pass the necessary parameters needed by the function.

For you to be able to choose where to place these logic, think about changing UI. An example would be a method for assigning a text for TextView could be done on the Fragment/Activity level but the one calling it is the ViewModel.